# support foreign chars

Tags: php, mysql

I use PHP/mySQL combo and sometimes see foreign characters entered with some names. I see them stored properly in mySQL but when they output in a browsers there's some garbage.
How to I support these on my website? I'm not trying to support all, just a few basic perhaps.

Example below:

```
é
```

Comment: What is the charset that you use on your page?

Comment: don't forget to query SET NAMES utf8 before any queries

Comment: PHP fix that worked in my case: stripslashes(htmlentities($wordWithEncodeChars, ENT_QUOTES));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to ensure that you're correctly understanding

- the charset the form is submitted with
- the encoding handing within PHP (which is atrocious)
- the encoding MySQL is using in the database
- the encoding you're telling the browser your document has

If any of these steps messes up, you'll have problems at some point.

I suggest you use utf8 for everything you have control over.

[FAQ for handling encoding in PHP](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/php_charset_encoding_FAQ.html)

Answer (score 1):

Fear no evil as you walk through the valley of unicode.

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem and, for me, it turned out to be the character encoding I used for MySQL.
To see what character sets and collation you are using in your databases try issuing the following statement:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, CHARACTER_SET_NAME, TABLE_COLLATION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY
  ON (TABLES.TABLE_COLLATION = COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY.COLLATION_NAME)
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('mysql', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA')
```

If they're not utf8 or similar, you should dig a little deeper into the whether or not what you're using supports those foreign characters.

I pull that statement from [this](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/useful-database-analysis-queries-with-information_schema) article, which you may find helpful. Also see [MySQL’s character sets and collations demystified](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/mysqls-character-sets-and-collations-demystified) for a pretty thorough background on the topic.